Show that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{\left(x^2+a^2\right)^2} dx = \frac{\pi}{2a}$
I am trying to show that
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x^2}{\left(x^2 + a^2\right)^2} dx = \frac\pi{2a}$$
for $a > 0$ using the Residue Theorem.
The formula I am using says
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx = 2\pi i\sum_{\nu=1}^k \operatorname{Res}\left(f ; a_\nu\right).$$
We have
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x^2}{\left(x^2 + a^2\right)^2} dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x^2}{(x + ai)^2(x - ai)^2} dx$$
which has the pole $x = ai$ in the upper half plane of order $2$. Now, we find
$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\frac{x^2}{(x + ai)^2} = \frac{6x^2}{(x + ia)^4} - \frac{8x}{(x + ia)^3} + \frac2{(x + ia)^2}$$
so
$$\operatorname{Res}(f;1)= \frac1{8a^2}.$$
Thus, we have that
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x^2}{\left(x^2 + a^2\right)^2} dx = 2\pi i\operatorname{Res}(f; ai) = 2\pi i \frac1{8a^2} = \frac{\pi i}{4a^2} \ne \frac\pi{2a}.$$
Where am I going wrong?

Not sure what formula did you use to find the residue. You need to differentiate $(z-ia)^2f(z)$ once, and substitute $z=ia$ in the derivative. I don't even try to memorize that, this just follows from examining the Laurent expansion. This method gives the correct answer, I just checked.

The problem is you computed the second derivative of $x^2/(x+ai)^2$. Since $ai$ is a pole of order two, you just need to compute the first derivative to apply Cauchy's integral formulae.

Excuse me sorry to ask this question. Is $$\arctan \frac{∞}{a} - \arctan \frac{-∞}{a}= \arctan {0} =π $$(because two infinity cancel each other out?)

@Gwen See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/711194/how-to-prove-that-limit-of-arctanx-as-x-tends-to-infinity-is-pi-2.

@Tri oh yes I completely forgot about it. You might wonder why I am asking this question. For knowing that you can see my answer and the comment I had written under it. :")

Cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1796022/computing-the-residue-of-a-rational-function

To compute the residue of a double pole, we need to compute the first derivative of the relevant factor of the integrand, not the second derivative.
Here's another method that builds on your approach: Applying the method of partial fractions to your complex factorization gives
$$\frac{x^2}{(x^2 + a^2)^2} = \frac{1}{4} \frac{1}{(x - ai)^2} - \frac{i}{4a} \frac{1}{x - ai} + g(x)$$
for some function $g$ analytic in a neighborhood of $a i$. In particular,
$$\operatorname{Res}(f; a i) = -\frac{i}{4 a} ,$$
and continuing with your computation as in the question statement gives the desired answer:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x^2 \,dx}{(x^2 + a^2)^2}
= 2 \pi i \operatorname{Res}(f; a i)
= 2 \pi i \left(-\frac{i}{4 a}\right)
= \boxed{\frac{\pi}{2 a}} .$$

Alternatively, the real partial fractions decomposition of $f$ the integrand is
$$\frac{x^2}{(x^2 + a^2)^2}
= -\frac{a^2}{(x^2 + a^2)^2} + \frac{1}{x^2 + a^2} ,$$ so we can rewrite the original integral as
$$-a^2 \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{(x^2 + a^2)^2} + \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2 + a^2} .$$ Denote the second integral by $I(a)$; it is elementary, but we can also evaluate it using the Residue Theorem:
$$I(a) = 2 \pi i \operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{1}{x^2 + a^2}; ai\right) = 2 \pi i \left(-\frac{i}{2 a}\right) = \frac{\pi}a .$$
Differentiating under the integral sign gives that
$$-\frac{\pi}{a^2} = I'(a) = -2 a \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{(x^2 + a^2)^2},$$ so
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{(x^2 + a^2)^2} = \frac{\pi}{2 a^3},$$ hence the original integral is
$$-a^2 \left(\frac{\pi}{2 a^3}\right) + \left(\frac{\pi}{a}\right) = \frac{\pi}{2 a} .$$

This integral can be easily evaluated by substituting $x=a\tan(\theta)$,
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{(x^2+a^2)^2}dx$$
$$=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{a^2\tan^2(\theta)}{a^4\sec^4(\theta)}a\sec^2(\theta)d\theta$$
$$=\frac{1}{a}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sin^2(\theta)d\theta$$
$$=\frac{1}{2a}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}(1-\cos(2\theta))d\theta\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \bigg(\because \cos(2\theta)=1-2\sin^2(\theta)\bigg)$$
$$=\frac{1}{2a}\bigg(\pi-0-\frac{\sin(\pi)-\sin(-\pi)}{2}\bigg)$$
$$=\frac{\pi}{2a}$$
$[QED]$

$$I:=\int_{-\infty}^ {\infty} \frac{x^2}{(x^2+a^2)^2}dx =\frac{1}{a}\int_{0}^ {\infty} \frac{t^{1.5-1}}{(t+1)^{1.5+0.5}}dx \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  ;x= a\sqrt{t} $$

$$B(a,b)= \int_0^1 t^{a-1}(1-t)^{b-1} dt= \int_{0}^ {\infty}\frac{t^{a-1}}{(1+t)^{a+b}}dt = \frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)}$$

$$I=\frac{B(0.5,1.5)}{a}=\frac{\pi}{2a} $$

$$\text{Res}(f(z) , ai)= \lim_{z\to ai}\frac{d}{dz}(z-ai)^2f(z)=\lim_{z\to ai}\frac{d}{dz}\left({\frac{z^2}{(z+ai)^2}}\right)=\lim_{z\to ai}\frac{2aiz}{(z+ai)^3}=-\frac{i}{4a}$$
Therefore:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x^2}{\left(x^2 + a^2\right)^2} dx = 2\pi i\text{Res}(f, ai) = -2\pi i \frac{i}{4a}=\frac{\pi}{2a}
$$

I'm using the most basic integration I know ( we just started classes a week ago)
I can rearrange your expression as:-
$$\int_{-∞}^{∞} \frac{x^2 + a ^2}{({x^2+a^2})^2}-\frac{a^2}{({x^2+a^2})^2} \ dx$$
$$=\int_{-∞}^{∞} (x^2+a^2)^{-1}-a^2(x^2+a^2)^{-2} \ dx$$
$$=\bigg(\dfrac{\arctan\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)}{a}\bigg)\bigg|_{-∞}^{∞}-a^2\bigg(\dfrac{\arctan\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)}{2a^3}+\dfrac{x}{2a^2\cdot\left(x^2+a^2\right)}\bigg)\bigg|_{-∞}^{∞}$$
$$I=\frac{π}{a} - a^2\frac{π}{2a^3}=\frac{π}{2a}$$
[QED]

I will be honest here. I haven't learnt definite integrals yet. I had to use a calculator at the last step. I don't understand how π appeared here. Our teacher will teach definite integrals next week :")

In this case, it is better to instead use integration by parts. Starting with
$$I=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\mathrm dx,\frac {x^2}{(x^2+a^2)^2}$$
Use $u=x$ and $\mathrm dv=\frac x{(x^2+a^2)^2},\mathrm dx$. You can integrate $\mathrm dv$ using u-substitution to get $v=-\frac 1{2(x^2+a^2)}$. That should give you the result immediately.

If you like, you can use IBP to get the answer just in a single step. In fact
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x^2}{\left(x^2 + a^2\right)^2} dx =-\frac12 \int_{-\infty}^\infty xd\bigg(\frac{1}{x^2+a^2}\bigg)=\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{x^2+a^2}dx=\frac\pi{2a}.$$
